# How can I restore the behavior where h and l stopped at the beginning and end of the line?

Tags: neovim, cursor-movement, default-settings, lunarvim

After quite some time of using Vim I wanted to switch to NeoVim and set it up with more IDE-like features.
So I googled and took the first thing I found ([LunarVim/nvim-basic-ide/](https://github.com/LunarVim/nvim-basic-ide/)), thinking I could change the few things I got used to with my old almost plain config. So far this has worked quite well.

But the one thing I can't seem to find is how to get back to the default behavior where the cursor doesn't jump to the next line. If I move with `h` to the beginning of a line I want it to stop there. Same for the end of a line and `l`. It's the default behavior for (Neo)Vim. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is controlled by the [`'whichwrap'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27whichwrap%27) setting.

Try this:

```
" Remove h and l from 'whichwrap'
set whichwrap-=h,l
```

Or just:

```
" Use defaults
set whichwrap&
```

I'm not sure how you configure LunarVim not to fiddle with this setting. Try running `:verbose set whichwrap?` to find out exactly what's setting it.

As a worst case scenario, you could try reverting to the defaults at the end of startup:

```
augroup fix_whichwrap
  au!
  au VimEnter * set whichwrap&
augroup END
```

FWIW, I'd personally recommend against using something like LunarVim, for precisely the reason that you're experiencing: systems like this can break things in hard to track-down ways. Use whatever plugins make you more productive, but install them one at a time as and when you need them: don't install a bunch of things preemptively.